# How to use cURL to post form to purewhois.com

Tags: html, forms, post, curl

I am trying to submit the form found here: http://www.purewhois.com/index.php

Using the following command:

```
curl --data "queryInput=microsoft.com@hidden=default&submit=search" \
http://www.purewhois.com/index.php
```

It doesn't seem to be working correctly.  I even tried the `-F` switch.  Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works?

> curl --data "queryInput=microsoft.com&output=default&submit=search"
>   http://www.purewhois.com/index.php

Comment: I think I see my typos.  I accidentally used @ instead of & and used the term "hidden" instead of the form field's name "output" in the query.  Thanks!